# How to set longitude and latitude using textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, latitude-longitude

How can I set the longitude and latitude using a textfield? I have tried making my textfield a double but it just seems to crash.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
    region.center.latitude = *(myTextField);
    region.center.longitude = *(myTextField1);
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


    MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"Test";
    ann.subtitle = @"test";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann];  
}
```

How I can make this work?

Comment: ***first and last point is I don't see textfield in your code***

Comment: Its called myTextField.

Comment: region.center.latitude = myTextField.text;
region.center.longitude = myTextField1.text;

Comment: @Shripada tried that but makes me to change it to *(myTextField);

Comment: Crash? So any error logs? Did you try debugging? Where is your issue exactly?

Comment: there are no logs. its an empty output and nothing loads in the simulator.

Comment: `region.center.latitude = *(myTextField);` what is that? can you explain this line please? it looks a big mess to me until further explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below Code:

Just get text from textFields and set latitude,longitude float value from text.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = [self.myTextField.text floatValue];
region.center.longitude = [self.myTextField1.text floatValue];
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];


MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Test";
ann.subtitle = @"test";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

}
```

Comment: i get your point but i get an error member reference base type 'double' is not  structure or union.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKPointAnnotation *annonation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D mycordinate;
mycordinate.latitude = [self.latitude floatValue];
mycordinate.longitude =[self.longitude floatValue];
annonation.coordinate = mycordinate;
[self.mapview addAnnotation:annonation];
```

In `self.latitude` store your latitude value and 
in `self.longitude` store your longitude value.

Comment: if possible then please approve the answer so that others are quickly find it.....